# Use arraylist to store the log events in memory - with rolling appender

Tags: java, arraylist, log4j

I'm going to extends rollingFileAppender. 
I have defined the size and the amount of the dile in log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.myApp.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.myApp.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

my extenstion should save the log event in memory and when there is error, to write them to the log.

I use      `ArrayList<LoggingEvent> loggingEvents = new ArrayList<>();`

But, I don't know what size to give the arrayList so it will still work with the sizes defined above as expected. Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: ArrayList resizes itself automatically. Why would you need to specify a specific size?

Comment: what will happen if there will not be error? When I use just rollingFileAppender I limit the size to be 20MB * 5. When I use my appender I can only give it ammount of events.

Comment: I would suggest that you just write to the appender all the time, not buffer things in the loggingEvents. If you buffer them and only write on an error, then you risk losing them if the JVM is stopped. Let Log4J do the buffering.